# SELECT statement using WHERE IN and HAVING COUNT fails

Tags: mysql, where-clause, having, where-in

I have the following query to return all user_attributes and attributes which have a specified tag:

```
SELECT `user_attributes`.*, `attributes`.*
FROM `user_attributes`
INNER JOIN `attributes` ON (`attributes`.`id` = `user_attributes`.`attribute_id`)
INNER JOIN `user_tags` ON (`attributes`.`id` = `user_tags`.`attribute_id`)
INNER JOIN `tags` ON (`user_tags`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id`)
WHERE `user_attributes`.`user_id` = '1'
    AND `tags`.`title` IN ('tag1')
```

I would like to adjust the query so that it finds all values that have 2 tags. At the moment I have:

```
SELECT `user_attributes`.*
FROM `user_attributes`
INNER JOIN `attributes` ON (`attributes`.`id` = `user_attributes`.`attribute_id`)
INNER JOIN `user_tags` ON (`attributes`.`id` = `user_tags`.`attribute_id`)
INNER JOIN `tags` ON (`user_tags`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id`)
WHERE `user_attributes`.`user_id` = '1'
    AND `tags`.`title` IN ('tag1', 'tag2')
    HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT `tags`.`title`) = 2)
```

Is it breaking because I'm using HAVING without a GROUP BY?

Comment: HAVING should be used in combination with GROUP BY indeed. MySQL is the only database what will handle HAVING without GROUP BY as some kind off WHERE

Comment: Thanks, if you add this as an answer I will accept it. I'd been putting the GROUP BY in the wrong place and getting a syntax error. Needs to be before the HAVING and after the WHERE AND.

Comment: You probably need to `GROUP BY user_attributes.attribute_id` in this specific query (since you say that you want to return all user_attributes ...) But `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` is valid and useful in other cases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HAVING should be used in combination with GROUP BY indeed. MySQL is the only database what will handle HAVING without GROUP BY as some kind off WHERE

**Some more proof for the downvoter..**

```
MySQL http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba8d6/3  (this is WRONG and looks like HAVING IS USED AS WHERE) 
Oracle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ba8d6/1 (this is correct ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression Oracle is missing the GROUP BY)
Postgresql http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/ba8d6/2 (this is correct ERROR: column "data.username" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function   Postgresql wants to have an GROUP BY
```